# Enable access to Kubernetes Dashboard without kubectl proxy

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kube-proxy, kubernetes-dashboard, kube-apiserver

If I move a relevant config file and run `kubectl proxy` it will allow me to access the Kubernetes dashboard through this URL:

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

However if I try to access the node directly, without `kubectl proxy`, I will get a 403 Forbidden.

```
http://dev-master:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/#!/login
```

Our kubernetes clusters are hidden inside a private network that users need to VPN in to; furthermore only some of us can talk to the master node of each of our clusters after authenticating to the VPN. As such, running `kubectl proxy` is a redundant step, and choosing the appropriate config file for each cluster is an additional pain, especially when we want to compare the state of different clusters.

What needs to be changed to allow "anonymous" HTTP access to the dashboard of these already-secured kubernetes master nodes?

Comment: You can expose `kubernetes-dashboard` service via `NodePort`, find solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863271/not-able-to-login-to-kubernetes-dashboard-from-hhtp-url-since-local-host-of-the/53869268#53869268).

Answer (score 3):

You would want to set up a Service (either NodePort or LoadBalancer) for the dashboard pod(s) to expose it to the outside world (well, outside from the PoV of the cluster, which is still an internal network for you).

Comment: After exposing 443 via a LoadBalancer service what URL should I be hitting? I can't access it like other services on my network at `https://IPADDRESS`