# Run a web page similar to kubernetes dashboard

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dashboard, kubernetes-dashboard

I a want to run a web page similar like kubernetes dashboard.The web page takes input from the user and generates a small file but i want the web page to be loaded without using any server. kubernetes is deploying a pod and bringing up the web page i want to do the same.If kubernetes is also using a server how is it using it(is it directly downloading it with the OS in the pod or how is kubernetes doing it).

Overview I want to know how kubernetes dashboard is getting deployed is it using a server if so how is it getting the server installed in the kubernetes pod else how is it bring up the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Kubernetes plays the role as an orchestrator and provides sufficient way for building communication channels between containers in the cluster and uses Docker by default as a container [runtime](https://docs.docker.com/engine/docker-overview/).

Containers represent run-time environment for images, however images consist with OS layer and application binaries, a good explanation you can find [here](https://www.sdxcentral.com/containers/definitions/what-is-docker-container-open-source-project/). In order to build own image you might consider two ways to afford this: create an image from existing one in [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) or compose image from [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).To store the customized image might be the option to push it into Docker Hub repository or stand for some private isolated repo by deploying a [Registry server](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/).

When you are ready with an image, and you plan to implement application in Kubernetes cluster, that's a good time to create first microservice. Although, there are tons of materials about Kubernetes cluster and its run-time engine [architecture](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/cloud-controller/) in the globe, I would focus on the application deployment lifecycle.

[Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) is the main mechanism which defines how are Pods should to be implemented within a cluster and provides specific configuration for further application run-time workflow.

[Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) describes a way how the particular Pod will communicate with other resources within a cluster, providing endpoint IP address and port where your application will respond.

In general scenario with Kubernetes [Dashboard](http://ttps://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/), the method in use `kubectl proxy` will expose the application by proxying gateway between host and Kubernetes API, which is more like for testing purposes and not secure, in comparison with [Nodeport](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) type which brings more convenient way to make application accessible outside the cluster, as described in this Stack [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863271/not-able-to-login-to-kubernetes-dashboard-from-hhtp-url-since-local-host-of-the/53869268#53869268).

I encourage you to get some more learning stuff in the official Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/).